# How is data transferred in a circuit switched network?

Tags: protocol-theory

Packet switched networks break data up into packets. Obviously on a circuit switched network it needs to break a 100MB file up into parts, so what is the equivalent?

I once heard the term "packet" used to refer to whatever it is the circuit switched network uses to transfer data, but it seems to be the general consensuses that only a packet switched network has packets

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's define "network" a little more broadly.  A network is simply a shared path of multiple endpoints to communicate data across.  Networks exist in nature and in computers.  The nervous system in your body is a network among which neurons communicate.

Now, let's look at a standard POTS (plain old telephone system) network. Old school,"give me klondike 411" type stuff.  In this world, you picked up the phone and communicated your desired endpoint.  The network was then arranged to give you a complete end-to-end circuit and then you simply sent the data across without care. This, is a circuit switched network.  The end-to-end path is determined once upon setup and then stays that way until the "call" is done with.

Packet switched is more dynamic.  Every single unit of data includes it's endpoint information and the network forwards the data across on a unit-by-unit basis.

I hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once a connection is established in a circuit-switched network, both participants can send data to each other as a continuous stream of bits or octets/words. This usually works well with a simple stream like audio/voice but not so well with more complex or multiplexed structured data. Various provisions were made for that on different circuit-switching protocols, but not all of them interact perfectly - things can get very complex.

In practical life, structured data is packetized like on a packet-switched network (which also simplifies interaction), requiring some kind of framing to mark those packets, e.g. HDLC. That way, the network type is only a matter of the lower network layers and the higher layers can ignore the subtleties.

Answer (score -2):

A circuit switched network can also transport packets. The difference between a packet-switched and a circuit-switched network is in how the routing is done:

- In a packet-switched network, each packet has a source/destination address and is routed *individually* through the entire network. So it is possible that two consecutive packets (transporting the data of the same “file”) go through different network nodes.
- In a circuit-switched network, the route is typically computed when you establish a connection. So the route is determined once for all before any data transfer, and every packet will follow the same route. Each intermediate node will associate a label to this route, so that packets don't need to include a source/destination address anymore, they can just include their routing label, and each intermediate node will simply read the label, and transmit the packet on the appropriate link.

In real life things are usually more complex, some examples:

- a packet-switched network will behave a little bit like a circuit-switched network by caching already calculated routes, which results in a performance gain (widely used on IP networks to reduce latencies).
- a circuit-switched network has re-routing protocols in case if a node fails. It's also very important in mobile networks, when a cellphone changes the base station it is connected to.

Comment: As phrased, this answer is rather misleading because circuit-switched networks have no idea what a packet is; at best they only provide constant bit-rate, constant delay bit streams which have no inherent packetization in them.  The answer doesn't seem to respond to the most basic question, which is how a file could be transferred via circuit switching

Comment: "A circuit switched network can also transport packets" is totally wrong

Comment: Don't see anything fundamentally wrong with my answer. You can send packets in a circuit-switched network even if the circuit-switched network has no concept of packets. Just like you can send JPEG files over TCP, even if there is no concept of an image in the TCP protocol. Also, you don't have to be sending data continuously on a circuit-switched network, even if your session is open and the bitrate reserved. Also do you see anything invalid about how the routing is done on both network types?